# Xamarin forms web view redirect failing

Tags: xamarin.forms

Got an iOS issue with my XamForms web view. I have set the info.plist to allow `NSAllowsArbitraryLoads`

My URL is `https://myurl.co.uk//rewards.html?sso=<GUID>&cid=<ID>` - nothing out of the ordinary. When I hit go on Safari as a direct link (I type it in), the URL shows. No such luck on the Xamarin form view. Here I get the following throwback

```
2019-11-21 10:28:58.626694+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429154] [Common] _BSMachError: port 7903; (os/kern) invalid capability (0x14) "Unable to insert COPY_SEND"
2019-11-21 10:28:59.295901+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429327] [unspecified] container_system_group_path_for_identifier: error = (container_error_t)53
2019-11-21 10:28:59.522399+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429169] Connection 1: received failure notification
2019-11-21 10:28:59.522545+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429169] Connection 1: failed to connect 12:8, reason -1
2019-11-21 10:28:59.522637+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429169] Connection 1: encountered error(12:8)
2019-11-21 10:28:59.523727+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429290] Task <D57B535F-7434-4B60-9EBF-0490B8FCF2EF>.<0> HTTP load failed, 0/0 bytes (error code: -1003 [12:8])
2019-11-21 10:28:59.523851+0000 Perks.iOS[44969:1429290] NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1003
```

Any ideas on what is causing the issue? When I put the URL through postman, there is some JS on the redirected page, but it's not getting that far, so I'm guessing it's the web view at fault

Answer (score 0):

**Cause:** Since iOS 9, iOS will only allow your application to communicate with servers that implement best-practice security by default. Values must be set in Info.plist to enable communication with insecure servers.

**Solution:** Add the following code in your `info.plist` to trust your domain.

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
    <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
    <dict>
      <key>myurl.co.uk</key>
      <dict>       
       <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
       <false/>
       <key>NSExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
       <true/>
       <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
       <true/>
     </dict>
</dict>
```

Comment: I've made these changes to the info.plist but am still seeing the same errors as above

Comment: error code 1003 always appears because of service. So make sure that you can access the url on browser .

Comment: That's the insane part. Copy and paste to Safari and it works. Use in the app - nada.

Comment: It works fine on my side ,so you can provide your sample so that I can test it .

Comment: I can, but will need to email it (commercial product)

Comment: You just need to create a new project and move the part of code to it .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202869/discussion-between-lucas-zhang-msft-and-nodoid).